# While parsing JSON data, I get different result, from same url

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

**Problem Statement:** Every time whenever I refresh viewController, then  I get different values.

**Required Solution:** Whenever I refresh, it should fetch same values.

**Coding Stuff:** 
Below I have get values from JSON parsing via url. After fetching values, it pass to the 'setChart() function as a parameter.'

```
 override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var completedCalls = 0
            for i in 0..<strDates.count {
                Alamofire.request("http://api.fixer.io/\(strDates[i])?base=USD").responseJSON { response in
                    if let arr = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]
                    {
                        completedCalls += 1
                        let inrc = (arr["rates"]?["INR"] as? Double)!
                        print(inrc)
                        self.sValues.append(inc)
                        print(sValues) 
                        //It prints values here.
                        if completedCalls = strDates.count {
                            DispatchQueue.main {
                                setChart(dataPoints: strDates, values: sValues)
                            }
                        }
                    }
           }
  }
```

**setChart() Function**

```
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
            barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

            for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [values[i]])
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }

            let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "INR Rates(₹)/$")
            let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
            barChartView.data = chartData
            barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 65
            barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 70
            barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
            barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
            barChartView.data?.setDrawValues(false)

        }
   }
```

Comment: Yes, it's right, but I'm passing same dates to fetch values. again whenever I refresh.

Comment: I'm parsing INR values of last 30 days, from currentDate. So it should get same values of last 30 days.

Comment: If I'm going someWhere wrong please correct me.

Comment: Why dont you show us some results and tell us why they are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're issuing a sequence of asynchronous requests, but you have no assurances the order in which they'll complete.

I would suggest capturing the results in a dictionary, with the `strDates` as the key. Then you can extract them in the correct order when presenting the results.

---

So, I'm assuming that assuming that `sValues` is defined as:

```
var sValues = [Double]()
```

Change that to:

```
var sValues = [String: Double]()
```

And then, rather than:

```
self.sValues.append(inc)
```

You would do:

```
self.sValues[strDates[i]] = inc
```

Then, in your charting code, iterate through `strDates` array, and look up the `sValues` using those date strings.

Comment: Ok Sir, I'll get results in dictionary.